# Delete group membership in stormpath 0.10 using sdk

Tags: node.js, stormpath, group-membership

I want to delete a group membership without deleting the group or account. I don't have any delete method in stormpath's sdk for node.js.

I am using 0.10.1 version of stormapath.

```
'use strict';
var utils = require('../utils');
var InstanceResource = require('./InstanceResource');

function GroupMembership() {
   GroupMembership.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}
utils.inherits(GroupMembership, InstanceResource);

GroupMembership.prototype.getAccount = function     getGroupMembershipAccount(/* [options,] callback */) {
    var self = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var callback = args.pop();
    var options = (args.length > 0) ? args.shift() : null;

    return self.dataStore.getResource(self.account.href, options, require('./Account'), callback);
};

GroupMembership.prototype.getGroup = function getGroupMembershipGroup(/* [options,] callback */) {
  var self = this;
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var callback = args.pop();
  var options = (args.length > 0) ? args.shift() : null;

  return self.dataStore.getResource(self.group.href, options, require('./Group'), callback);
};

module.exports = GroupMembership;
```

This is the code in GroupMembership.js file. It does not have delete method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GroupMemebership inherits from InstanceResource which gives it a delete method.

Do you mind posting some code so we can see what you are doing?

If you can get the GroupMembership, it should be as simple as:

```
groupMemebership.delete(function(err){
  if(!err){
    console.log("deleted");
  }
})
```